# trouble with iframe and php

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I have an issue and need some clarification

I have a wordpress site i am building and every time i try and code jquery into the theme i get errors so my work around has been to use two iframes....one being the menu

Can you have a link in a iframe load that links content in the area outside the iframe...if so how....if not is there a work around.

```
<iframe src="http://www.heartkidsplayshop.com/wp-content/themes/outreach/menu/all-examples.html" width="620" height="110" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `target="_parent"` on the links in the iFrame.